# Complex numbers and euclidean geometry

Tags: complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

The following complex number:

$z_{1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i$

is the head vertex of an Isosceles triangle, which is inside a Circumscribed circle (centered at (0,0)).

The complex numbers $z_{2},z_{3}$ are the other vertices of the triangle, where:
$z_{2}=1$

The complex number w satisfy: $w=\prod_{i=1}^{3}z_{i}$

Calculate the sum:

$S=w+w^{2}+w^{3}+w^{4}+...+w^{4n}$

The beginning should be to find $z_{3}$. I know that $z_{1}$ has a radius of 1 and an angle of 330 degrees, therefore it's in the 4th quadrant. $z_{2}$ is on the x-axis, this means that the circle has a radius of 1 as well. How do I proceed ? Assuming that I do find the 3rd complex number, how to I solve it from 
there ?

I have tried plotting it, and something is not right. Isn't $z_{3}$ on the circle. How can it be ?

Any assistance will be most appreciated !

[image]

Comment: z3 has to be on the circle?

Comment: I have a final answer according to which z3=1cis(300)

Comment: No, it's definitely z2=1

Comment: I see the problem.  I was thinking equilateral triangle, the problem says isosceles.  Take the triangle you have, and move and equal distance around to the other side of $z_1,$ the same distance as $z_1$ is form $z_2$

Answer (score 2):

$z_1 = \cos(-30^\circ) + i\sin(-30^\circ)\\
z_2 = \cos(0^\circ) + i\sin(0^\circ)\\
z_3 = \cos(-60^\circ) + i\sin(-60^\circ)$

$\omega = z_1z_2z_3 = \cos(-90^\circ) + i\sin(-90^\circ)= - i$

$\omega + \omega^2 + \omega^3 + \omega^4 = 0$

Comment: I may have took it to the wrong direction trying to find z3 with geometry...

Comment: Oh, I think your picture was very helpful.  I just had equilateral on the brain, when the problem said isosceles.

Comment: the circle must be centered in (0,0). It's part of the question, I now see I didn't wrote it. So Doug's solution is fine I think

Comment: You are right, but regarding your comment, you are right. Who said that z3 is on the circle ? Even if it is centered at (0,0). Can z3 not be on it?

Comment: @user3275222 `Who said that z3 is on the circle` All three vertices of a triangle are on the circumscribed circle, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

$z_1$ was a head vertex.  So the interior angle from $z_1$ to $z_2$ is the same as the angle from $z_1$ to $z_3$.

You figured that $z_1$ represents the angle $330$ and $z_2$ represents the angle $0$.

So it follows that $z_3$ represents the angle $300$.

So $z_3=r*(\cos 300 + i\sin 300)=\frac 12 - i\frac {\sqrt {3}}2$.

Now, take it away.

....

Hint of things to come:  you'll soon discover that if $a=\frac {360k}n$ and $w=\cos a +i\sin a $, then $w^n=1$.  So $z_1^6=1;z_3^3=1$.

That will become *very* important soon.